# Adding a background image using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import Background from './img/steamledges.jpg';

const myStyles = {
     backgroungImage: `url( ${Background} )`,
     height: '50vh', 
     backgroungSize: 'cover',
}
```

i tried using this code and it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Aliyu! Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) written in e.g. [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) and it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: you have written `backgroungImage` and `backgroungSize`. Is this a typo in question or in your code?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your problem, is you want to add an image using the inline-style `backgroundImage` right ?

What about this ? Instead of using your image as a component because it won't works. Only SVG can be used as component when you import them.
Check it out :

```
`backgroundImage: require('./path/to/your/img.extension)`
```

Tell me if you've solved the problem

Comment: @AliyuKamilu So could you please accept the answer,  thanks!